# Magento 2 Event or Plugin after order status update in admin

Tags: magento2, orders

I want to perform some activity after order status update in magento 2 admin order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to try this plugin.

```
app/code/VENDOR/EXTENSION/etc/di.xml
```

add following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="my_order_state_plugin"
                type="VENDOR\EXTENSION\Model\Plugin\Orderstateplugin"/>
    </type>

</config>
```

Now create plugin file `Orderstateplugin.php`

```
app/code/VENDOR/EXTENSION/Model/Plugin/Orderstateplugin.php
```

add this code.

```
public function afterSave(
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $subject,
    $result
) {
    $result->getState() // get order state.
       
    // do you custom code

    return $result;
}
```